# Change the website default Language (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In wordpress when I change the default site language to be Italian, my admin panel changed to Italian  as well , How I can set two default languages one for the website visitors and the other for the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into your theme's functions.php file (assuming you want US English):

```
function english_admin( $locale ) {
if ( is_admin() ) {
    return 'en_US';
}
return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'english_admin' );
```